# How do I correctly get my code to test out of a recursion function for binary search?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to use my binary search function to find a number that is at the head or tail of the list, my function doesn't correctly output the result. How do I fix this?

I've tried using my function to search for b = 1 and b = 562. For both cases, my function outputted "{} is not found in the list".

```
# initialize values
a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 56, 78, 234, 562]
b = 562
head = 0
tail = len(a) - 1

# binary search method
def binary_search(a, b, head, tail):
    mid = int(len(a) / 2)
    if b == a[mid]:
        print("{} is found in the list".format(b))
# this is where I need HELP
    elif len(a) == 1 or len(a) == 2 or len(a) == 3:
        if b == head or b == tail or b == mid:
            print("{} is found in the list".format(b))
        else:
            print("{} is not found in the list".format(b))
# this is all GOOD
    elif b > a[mid]:
        a = a[mid:tail]
        binary_search(a, b, head, tail)
    elif b < a[mid]:
        a = a[head:mid]
        binary_search(a, b, head, tail)

binary_search(a, b, head, tail)
```

I expect the function to output "{} is found in the list"

Comment: `b == head or b == tail or b == mid` is comparing a *value* against *indexes* into the list - it would be purest coincidence if that was true (and is impossible with b=562, since the list isn't nearly that long).  You want `b == a[head]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is awkward code.  Think about *why* you are checking against each of these values, and try to simplify the logic.

```
elif len(a) == 1 or len(a) == 2 or len(a) == 3:
    if b == head or b == tail or b == mid:
        print("{} is found in the list".format(b))
    else:
        print("{} is not found in the list".format(b))
```

For instance:

```
elif len(a) <= 3:
    if b in [head, mid, tail]:
```

... is at least easier to read.

Your logic error is here:

```
    if b == head or b == tail or b == mid:
```

`b` is the target value; `head, tail, mid` are indices into the list.  Since there are only 11 items in the list, none of them will ever equal 562.  Try:

```
    if b == a[head] ...
```

Comment: This isnt the only error. This will cause an "out of bound index error"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
b == head or b == tail or b == mid
```

is comparing the value you are looking for against indexes of the list

Secondly

```
 binary_search(a, b, head, tail)
```

assumes that the head and tail stays the same but however you just divided the list in the previous statement

```
a = a[mid:tail]
```

so the head is always 0 and the tail is always len(a)-1

Thirdly
Since your code depends on dividing the list into length of 3 or smaller you should handle cases where b=a[mid] before reaching a length of 3 or lower

So you should make your first if condition

```
 elif b >= a[mid]:
```

Lastly

```
a = a[mid:tail]
```

since tail refers to the index of the last element you are excluding it since in array slicing your end should be equal to the index of the last element you want +1

Corrected Code:

```
# initialize values
a = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 56, 78, 234, 562]
b = 1
head = 0
tail = len(a) - 1

# binary search method
def binary_search(a, b, head, tail):

    print(head,tail)
    mid = int(len(a) / 2)
    if b == a[mid]:
        print("{} is found in the list".format(b))
# this is where I need HELP
    elif len(a) == 1 or len(a) == 2 or len(a) == 3:
        if b == a[head] or b == a[tail] or b == a[mid]:
            print("{} is found in the list".format(b))
        else:
            print("{} is not found in the list".format(b))
# this is all GOOD
    elif b >= a[mid]:
        a = a[mid:tail+1]
        binary_search(a, b, 0, len(a)-1)
    elif b < a[mid]:
        a = a[head:mid]
        binary_search(a, b, 0, len(a)-1)

binary_search(a, b, head, tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have problem here:

```
a = a[mid:tail]
```

In this case `tail` element will not be included. Also `mid` element will be included, which you don't want, because you've already checked it. So this line should be changed to:

```
a = a[mid+1:tail+1]
```

Second, as jasonharper mentioned in the comment, you have problem here:

```
elif len(a) == 1 or len(a) == 2 or len(a) == 3:
    if b == head or b == tail or b == mid:
```

You are comparing against indexes, while you should compare elements. Also the first line could be optimized:

```
elif len(a) <= 3:
    if b == a[head] or b == a[tail] or b == a[mid]:
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Should I also change a[head:mid] to a[head-1:mid-1]?

Comment: No. Head will be included, and mid will be excluded, like it should be.

Comment: @Heavy this is incorrect as he didnt have a case for handling b==a[mid] before having a case of len(a) <=3